# Kendo Grid and one row of JSON data and a single row of data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I feed JSON results to My Kendo Grid; seems like when I have one row of data, the grid can't function?

Following works:

```
<DocumentElement>
    <ResultXml>
        <NoData>1</NoData>
    </ResultXml>
    <ResultXml>
        <NoData>2</NoData>
    </ResultXml>
</DocumentElement>";
```

and this doesn't work:

```
<DocumentElement>
    <ResultXml>
        <NoData>1</NoData>
    </ResultXml>
</DocumentElement>";
```

EDIT to clear out above xml is converted to json before being fed to the grid (I included the xml version of the json for readability purposes)
Obviously above is xml; after using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert, I get the following JSON results to feed to my grid (none of which works):

```
{"DocumentElement":{"ResultXml":"Nothing to display"}}
{"DocumentElement":{"ResultXml":{"field":"Nothing to display"}}}
```

Following works, but I want to avoid sending an empty field if I don't have to

```
{"DocumentElement":{"ResultXml":[{"NoData":null},{"NoData":"Nothing to display"}]}}
```

End of Edit

here's my Kendo Grid:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    sortable: true,
    groupable: true,
    scrollable: true,
    height: "600px",
    pageable: { pageSizes: 9 },
    dataSource:
    {
        transport:
        {
            read: function (options) {
                $.ajax("/Controller/Action?param=" + paramVal, 
                 success: function (result) {
                    var jResult = $.parseJSON(result);
                    options.success(jResult.DocumentElement.ResultXml);
                });
            }
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Dude, are you sure that <node>blah blah</node> is JSON? You should treat this as XML and you're good to go

Comment: haha thanks! that's a valid point :) I forgot to include the part where I turn the xml to json; I'll edit the question further down. thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can hardcode the json string when sending it back to client; I would've liked to have the xml version of saying I have empty dataset; but I guess this'll do, unless someone can suggest something better;

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlResult))
{
    //No data: 
    jsonData = "{\"DocumentElement\":{\"ResultXml\":[{\"NoData\":\"Nothing to display\"}]}}";
}
else
{
    //Turn xml data to Json:
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xmlResult);
    jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the field name does not need double quotes. Ex/ name\value pair as in {name: "Bob Mazzo"}

Comment: I think the problem has to do with treating the "field:val" pair as an object vs. an array; when I have two instances of "field:val" JsonConvertor turns it into an array; but where there's only one instance, it becomes a single object; So I have to fight between Kendo's version of JSON datasource and Newton's way of conversion; JsonConvertor is right in not creating the array; Kendo is wrong for not displaying the fields if they're not in a JSON array

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that there are 2 definition (one for View,the other for retrieving data) in your controller and the View calls the other one as below?

**Controller:**

```
//!!! This is for calling "CustomAjaxBinding" view
public ActionResult CustomAjaxBinding()
{
    return View();
}

//!!! This is for retrieving data called from "CustomAjaxBinding" View
public ActionResult CustomAjaxBinding_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var dataContext = new SampleEntities();

    //Convert to view model to avoid JSON serialization problems due to circular references.
    IQueryable<OrderViewModel> result = dataContext.Orders.Select(o => new OrderViewModel
    {
        OrderID = o.OrderID,
        ShipCity = o.ShipCity,
        ShipCountry = o.ShipCountry,
        ShipName = o.ShipName
    });
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);      
}
```

**View (name is "CustomAjaxBinding")**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.Order>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ShipCity);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ShipCountry);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ShipName);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()

        //!!! Call "CustomAjaxBinding_Read" not CustomAjaxBinding
        .Read(read => read.Action("CustomAjaxBinding_Read", "Grid"))
    )
)
```

Regards...